# Install 32 bit Nvidia drivers alongside 64 bit

Tags: nvidia

Windows programs run in Wine seem to require 32 bit drivers, but the Nvidia drivers conflict with versions (32 bit and 64 bit don't have equal versions). Is it possible to solve the conflicts somehow?

Edit:
The program that I'm trying to use is Roblox Player (it is relevant for other 32 bit Windows programs that utilize graphics). It just won't start with whatever error it wants to fail with (OpenGL, Vulkan, etc.).

The specific error log is here (from stderr of the program, using Wine):

```
002c:err:wineboot:process_run_key Error running cmd L"C:\\windows\\system32\\winemenubuilder.exe -a -r" (126).
0064:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 29 not handled, platform 1.
0064:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 29 not handled, platform 1.
0064:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 29 not handled, platform 1.
0064:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 29 not handled, platform 1.
0064:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 20 not handled, platform 1.
0064:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 20 not handled, platform 1.
0084:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 29 not handled, platform 1.
0084:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 29 not handled, platform 1.
0084:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 29 not handled, platform 1.
0084:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 29 not handled, platform 1.
0084:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 20 not handled, platform 1.
0084:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 20 not handled, platform 1.
002c:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 29 not handled, platform 1.
002c:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 29 not handled, platform 1.
002c:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 29 not handled, platform 1.
002c:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 29 not handled, platform 1.
002c:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 20 not handled, platform 1.
002c:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 20 not handled, platform 1.
0024:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 29 not handled, platform 1.
0024:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 29 not handled, platform 1.
0024:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 29 not handled, platform 1.
0024:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 29 not handled, platform 1.
0024:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 20 not handled, platform 1.
0024:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 20 not handled, platform 1.
00bc:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 29 not handled, platform 1.
00bc:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 29 not handled, platform 1.
00bc:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 29 not handled, platform 1.
00bc:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 29 not handled, platform 1.
00bc:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 20 not handled, platform 1.
00bc:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 20 not handled, platform 1.
0104:fixme:kernelbase:AppPolicyGetThreadInitializationType FFFFFFFA, 0247FEF8
0024:err:winediag:check_version ntlm_auth was not found or is outdated. Make sure that ntlm_auth >= 3.0.25 is in your path. Usually, you can find it in the winbind package of your distribution.
0024:err:ntlm:ntlm_LsaApInitializePackage no NTLM support, expect problems
0024:fixme:file:NtLockFile I/O completion on lock not implemented yet
0118:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 29 not handled, platform 1.
0118:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 29 not handled, platform 1.
0118:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 29 not handled, platform 1.
0118:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 29 not handled, platform 1.
0118:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 20 not handled, platform 1.
0118:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 20 not handled, platform 1.
0120:fixme:kernelbase:AppPolicyGetThreadInitializationType FFFFFFFA, 0247FEF8
0118:err:winediag:check_version ntlm_auth was not found or is outdated. Make sure that ntlm_auth >= 3.0.25 is in your path. Usually, you can find it in the winbind package of your distribution.
0118:err:ntlm:ntlm_LsaApInitializePackage no NTLM support, expect problems
0118:fixme:file:NtLockFile I/O completion on lock not implemented yet
0118:fixme:process:SetProcessShutdownParameters (00000100, 00000001): partial stub.
0104:err:wininet:HTTP_ParseDateAsAsctime unexpected weekday L"-1"
0104:err:wininet:HTTP_ParseDate unexpected date format L"-1"
0104:fixme:wininet:create_cache_entry INTERNET_FLAG_NEED_FILE is not supported correctly
0120:err:wininet:HTTP_ParseDateAsAsctime unexpected weekday L"-1"
0120:err:wininet:HTTP_ParseDate unexpected date format L"-1"
0120:fixme:wininet:create_cache_entry INTERNET_FLAG_NEED_FILE is not supported correctly
0104:err:wininet:HTTP_ParseDateAsAsctime unexpected weekday L"-1"
0104:err:wininet:HTTP_ParseDate unexpected date format L"-1"
0104:fixme:wininet:create_cache_entry INTERNET_FLAG_NEED_FILE is not supported correctly
0150:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 29 not handled, platform 1.
0150:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 29 not handled, platform 1.
0150:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 29 not handled, platform 1.
0150:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 29 not handled, platform 1.
0150:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 20 not handled, platform 1.
0150:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 20 not handled, platform 1.
0104:err:wininet:HTTP_ParseDateAsAsctime unexpected weekday L"-1"
0104:err:wininet:HTTP_ParseDate unexpected date format L"-1"
0104:fixme:wininet:create_cache_entry INTERNET_FLAG_NEED_FILE is not supported correctly
0150:err:winediag:check_version ntlm_auth was not found or is outdated. Make sure that ntlm_auth >= 3.0.25 is in your path. Usually, you can find it in the winbind package of your distribution.
0150:err:ntlm:ntlm_LsaApInitializePackage no NTLM support, expect problems
0104:err:wininet:HTTP_ParseDateAsAsctime unexpected weekday L"-1"
0104:err:wininet:HTTP_ParseDate unexpected date format L"-1"
0104:fixme:wininet:create_cache_entry INTERNET_FLAG_NEED_FILE is not supported correctly
0150:fixme:thread:GetThreadUILanguage : stub, returning default language.
0150:fixme:thread:GetThreadUILanguage : stub, returning default language.
0158:fixme:kernelbase:AppPolicyGetThreadInitializationType FFFFFFFA, 0514FEF8
0150:fixme:ntdll:NtQuerySystemInformation info_class SYSTEM_PERFORMANCE_INFORMATION
0150:fixme:thread:GetThreadUILanguage : stub, returning default language.
0150:fixme:thread:GetThreadUILanguage : stub, returning default language.
0104:err:wininet:HTTP_ParseDateAsAsctime unexpected weekday L"-1"
0104:err:wininet:HTTP_ParseDate unexpected date format L"-1"
0104:fixme:wininet:create_cache_entry INTERNET_FLAG_NEED_FILE is not supported correctly
0104:err:wininet:HTTP_ParseDateAsAsctime unexpected weekday L"-1"
0104:err:wininet:HTTP_ParseDate unexpected date format L"-1"
0104:fixme:wininet:create_cache_entry INTERNET_FLAG_NEED_FILE is not supported correctly
0024:fixme:kernelbase:AppPolicyGetProcessTerminationMethod FFFFFFFA, 0032FEAC
0118:fixme:kernelbase:AppPolicyGetProcessTerminationMethod FFFFFFFA, 0032FEAC
0150:fixme:keyboard:LoadKeyboardLayoutW name L"00000409", flags 1, semi-stub!
0150:fixme:keyboard:X11DRV_ActivateKeyboardLayout 0x4090409, 0000: semi-stub!
0150:fixme:keyboard:X11DRV_ActivateKeyboardLayout setting keyboard of different locales not supported
0150:err:ole:com_get_class_object apartment not initialised
0150:err:vulkan:wine_vk_instance_load_physical_devices Failed to enumerate physical devices, res=-3
0150:err:vulkan:wine_vkCreateInstance Failed to load physical devices, res=-3
01ec:fixme:service:I_ScRegisterDeviceNotification Notification filters are not yet implemented.
info:  Game: RobloxPlayerBeta.exe
info:  DXVK: v1.9
info:  Built-in extension providers:
info:    Win32 WSI
info:    OpenVR
info:    OpenXR
info:  OpenVR: could not open registry key, status 2
warn:  OpenVR: Failed to locate module
info:  Enabled instance extensions:
info:    VK_KHR_get_surface_capabilities2
info:    VK_KHR_surface
info:    VK_KHR_win32_surface
0150:err:vulkan:wine_vk_instance_load_physical_devices Failed to enumerate physical devices, res=-3
0150:err:vulkan:wine_vkCreateInstance Failed to load physical devices, res=-3
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'dxvk::DxvkError'
```

All of the font errors seem unrelated, since some programs rune fine with them.

Comment: Sorry that I didn't have much details in it, I didn't have much time. So the drivers just don't like each others' versions and don't install.

Comment: Thank you for your point, I will edit it so.

Comment: sorry but "Windows programs run in Wine seem to require 32 bit drivers " and "but the Nvidia drivers conflict with versions (32 bit and 64 bit don't have equal versions)." are two different things.  "Install 32 bit Nvidia drivers alongside 64 bit" never going to happen but there is also no need for this Wine is always 32 bit and does not care if the system it is on is 64 bit. Ubuntu does not need a 32 bit display driver for this. 64 bit will handle whatever 32 bit throws at it.

Comment: Hmm, then what could be the problem? People wanted me to try the 32 bit drivers on the place I was asking originally.

Comment: + 64 bit windows programs using graphics work fine.